# Prove Borel $\sigma-$algebras generated by two topologies of $L^1_{loc}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ are equivalent

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Let $L^1_{loc}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ be equipped with the following topologies:

1. Strong topology, i.e., the base includes
   \begin{align}
   U_{\Omega,f,\epsilon} 
   = \left\{ g \in L^1_{loc} \colon \int_{\Omega} \vert f(x) - g(x)\vert d x < \epsilon 
   \right\}
   \end{align}
   where $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ is compact, $f \in L^1(\Omega),~\epsilon > 0$.
2. Distributional topology, i.e., the base includes
   \begin{align}
   W_{\phi, a, b} =
   \left\{
   g \in L^1_{loc} \colon \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} g(x) \phi(x) dx \in (a,b)
   \right\}
   \end{align}
   where $\phi \in C^{\infty}_c(\mathbb{R}^d),~a < b.$

Let $\mathcal{B}_s,~\mathcal{B}_d$ be the $\sigma-$algebras generated by the strong topology and the distributional topology, respectively. I want to show $\mathcal{B}_s=\mathcal{B}_d$. Since the weak-* open set is also (strongly) open, we deduce $\mathcal{B}_s \supset \mathcal{B}_d$. I'm stuck at the other direction.

I try to connect the two sets by using the fact: Given $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ compact and $h \in L^1_{loc}(\mathbb{R}^d)$, there exists $\eta_n \in C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ such that
\begin{align}
\int_\Omega \vert h(x) \vert d x =\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} h(x) \eta_n (x) dx.
\end{align}
However, I'm not able to proceed further. Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Can we find a a countable family of $\eta_n$ such that $\int_\Omega |h|= \sup_n \int h\eta_n$ holds for every $h$ ? If so, I might have a solution

Comment: I suppose not. The number of $\pm \chi_{[a,b]}$ with $a, b$ rational are uncountable.

Comment: why do you need the $\sup$ in your condition? if $h\neq0$, you can get the correct $\eta_n$ just by scaling. Am I missing something?

Comment: @supinf It is because the smoothness of $h$ and $\eta_n$ are different. Let choose $h  = 2\chi_{[0,1]}$, then we have to approximate $\chi_{[0,1]}$ by a sequence of smooth functions $\eta_n \in C_c^{\infty}$.

Comment: @macnguyen I still do not understand. Can't we just choose $\eta_n \in C_c^\infty$ as a function that is $1$ on $[-3,3]$? Then we would have $2$ on both sides. Why is an approximation needed?

Comment: @supinf I see, the correct example should be the function that changes sign like crazy, e.g. $h(x) = \chi_{(0,1]}(x) \sin \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$.

Comment: @macnguyen even then: first choose $\eta_0\in C_c^\infty$ as a nonnegative function which is supported in $(1/2,1)$. Then $\int h \eta_0$ is positive. Then we can choose $\eta_n := \eta_0 \int |h| (\int h \eta_0)^{-1}$.

Comment: @supinf Nice scaling. I suppose we can drop the sup in the last identity as you suggest. Yet I still don’t know how to apply this to solve the problem.